# Prove by induction that for every $n \ge 0$ the term $2^{2n+1} - 9n^2 + 3n -2$ is divisible by $54$

Tags: sequences-and-series, induction

What I get is $4 \cdot 54k + 27(n(n-1)) - 2$.

I understand first two terms but $-2$ is giving me a headache. I suppose to be true every term should be divisible by $54$. Or did I make wrong conclusion?

P. S: Is there mathjax tutorial?

Comment: `Is there mathjax tutorial` See [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for example.

Answer (score 4):

Let $f(n) = 2^{2n+1}-9n^2+3n-2$; then
\begin{align*}
  f(n+1)-4f(n) &= 2^{2n+3}-9(n+1)^2+3(n+1)-2-4(2^{2n+1}-9n^2+3n-2) \\
      &= 4\cdot 2^{2n+1} - 9n^2 - 18n - 9 + 3n+3-2-4(2^{2n+1}-9n^2+3n-2) \\
      &= 27n^2-27n  = 27n(n-1).
\end{align*}
Since either $n$ or $n-1$ is even, this expression is divisible by $54$. Since $4f(n)$ is divisible by $54$ (inductive assumption), so is $f(n+1)$.

Comment: I understand f(n+1), but how did you get 4f(n)? Also, is it allowed to do f(n+1) - 4f(n)?

Comment: I can compute the value of any expression I like; I chose $4f(n)$ because a) it was also divisible by $54$, and b) it made the nasty exponential term go away. There is not really any "allowed" here; you assume that $f(n)$ is divisible by $54$ and do what you need to do to show that $f(n+1)$ is as well.

Comment: If it bothers you, you can just start with the expression for $f(n+1)$ and try to rework it to find some copies of $f(n)$ inside it. What's left over will again be $27n(n-1)$.

Comment: Thank you for explanation. I wasn't sure how you got it, but I understand it now.

Comment: You're welcome.

Answer (score 1):

No, in general not every term needs to be divisible by $54$ in order for the whole expression to be divisible by $54$

Consider: $56-2$ is clearly divisible by $54$, even if neither $56$ nor $-2$ are.

At the same time, given that in *your* specific expression the first two terms *are* divisible by $54$, the remaining third term (the $-2$) should be as well in order for the whole expression to be. Given that it is not, you must have made a mistake.

Now, how did you get to that expression? I assume you got this when working on the inductive step? But how did you end up with both $k$ and $n$ in your expression? That certainly should not happen when you do an inductive proof for this one. So, please post your work so we can try and find your mistake... learning from your mistakes is always more educational than just presenting you with a correct proof.

Comment: I just wrote the way how I got to this term (see below). I totally agree with learning from your own mistakes, but I was warned that my questions on this site should be direct and concise. Thank you for helping me!

Answer (score 1):

$2^{2n+1}-9n^2 +3n -2 = 54k$

$2^{2n+1} =54k +9n^2 -3n +2$

$2^{2(n+1)+1} -9(n+1)^2 +3(n+1) -2=$ 
$2^2(54k +9n^2 -3n +2) -9(n+1)^2 +3(n+1) -2$

After I compute everything, I get this: $4\cdot54k +27(n(n+1)) -2.$

Comment: Sorry I was away for a bit ... OK, your approach is correct! ... you just made a mistake in working it all out ... when I work it out I get $4 \cdot 54k +27n(n-1)$

Comment: So I did make a mistake! Ha, I knew something was fishy about my result  and after your comment I checked it out again and got it right.

Comment: Glad you found your mistake! :)

Answer (score 1):

You want to prove the divisibility by induction, so let's calculate the first terms.

$\begin{cases}f(0)=0\\f(1)=0\\f(2)=0\end{cases}\quad$ all multiples of $54$.

So hypothetically if you would have an induction relation of the form:
$$f(n)=af(n-1)+bf(n-2)+cf(n-3)+d$$

With $d$ being a multiple of $54$ then your proof by induction would be successful.

In fact, we shall see that it is possible to calculate these coefficients $(a,b,c,d)$.

The solution is $f(n)=(2)\times \color{red}{4^n}+(-9n^2+3n-2)\times \color{red}{1^n}$

So we are searching for a characteristic equation, where $\color{red}4$ and $\color{red}1$ are roots.

Because the constant term $d$ is also $d\times 1^n$, then the degree of the term in $1^n$ is raised by $1$ and we don't need a triple root but only a double root.

So the characteristic equation is $$(x-1)^2(x-4)=x^3-6x^2+9x-4$$

Let's calculate $f(n+3)-6f(n+2)+9f(n+1)-4f(n)=\cdots=54$.

$d=54$ is a multiple of $54$ and you can launch your induction proof.

Answer (score 1):

(*Alternative approach, without induction*.) The following uses the notation $\,\mathcal{M}n\,$ to denote any integer multiple of $\,n\,$. The obvious rules apply $\,2 \cdot \mathcal{M}3 = \mathcal{M}6, \,\mathcal{M}3 \cdot \mathcal{M}3 = \mathcal{M}9\,$ etc.

- $\,4^k-1 = \mathcal{M}3\,$ for all $\,k \ge 0\,$, therefore:

$$\require{cancel}
\begin{align}
4^n - 1 &= (4-1)\cdot(4^{n-1}+\cdots+4+1) \\
 &=3 \cdot \big((4^{n-1}-1)+ \cdots + (4-1) + (\cancel{1} - \cancel{1}) + n\big) \tag{1}\\
 &= 3 \cdot (\mathcal{M}3 + n) \\
 &= \mathcal{M}9 + 3n
\end{align}
$$

- Using the previous result back in $\,(1)\,$:

$$
\begin{align}
\color{blue}{2 \cdot (4^n - 1)} &=6 \cdot \big((\mathcal{M}9+3(n-1))+ (\mathcal{M}9+3(n-2))+ \cdots + (\mathcal{M}9+3 \cdot 1) + n\big)\\
 &= \mathcal{M}54 + 18\big((n-1)+(n-2)+\cdots+1 \big) + 6n \\
 &= \mathcal{M}54 + 18 \cdot \frac{n(n-1)}{2}+6n \\
 &= \color{blue}{\mathcal{M}54 + 9 n^2 - 3n} \tag{2}
\end{align}
$$

It then follows straight from $\,(2)\,$ that: $$2^{2n+1} - 9n^2 + 3n -2 = \color{blue}{2 \cdot (4^n -1)} -9n^2+3n=\color{blue}{\mathcal{M}54 + \cancel{9 n^2} - \bcancel{3n}} - \cancel{9n^2} + \bcancel{3n}$$

Answer (score 0):

As [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1174078/242) this can be viewed as a special case of the first few terms of the Binomial Theorem. If you have not already (inductively) proved that, then we can easily prove this special case, viz.

$\!\begin{align}{\rm mod}\,\ \color{#c00}{a^3}\!:\,\  (1+ a)^n\, \ \  \equiv&\,\ \ 1 + na + n(n\!-\!1)/2\ a^2\qquad  {\rm i.e.}\ \ \color{darkorange}{P(n)}\\[.3em]
\Rightarrow\,\ \ (1+a)^{\color{}{n+1}}\! \equiv &\  (1 + na + n(n\!-\!1)/2\ a^2)(1 + \color{#0a0}a)\quad {\rm by}\ \ 1\!+\!a \ \ \rm times\ prior\\[.3em]
\equiv &\ \ 1\ \ \ +\,\ \ \ na + n(n\!-\!1)/2\ a^2\\[-.2em]
       &\ \ \ \ \ \ \  + \ \ \  \ 1\:\!\color{#0a0}a\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \,+\ \ \ \ \ \ n\,a\color{#0a0}a\ \ \ \ +\ \ \ \ n(n\!-\!1)n/2\ \color{#c00}{a^3}\\[.3em]
\equiv &\, \ 1\!+\! (n\!+\!1)a\!+\!n(n\!+\!1)/2\,a^2\ \ \ {\rm i.e.}\ \ \color{darkorange}{P({n\!+\!1})}\\[2pt]  
  \end{align}$

$\begin{align}\text{Thus for $\,a=3\,$ we get}\ \ 4^n &\equiv 1 + 3n + 9n(n-1)/2 \pmod{27}\\[.1em]
\Rightarrow\ \ 2\cdot 4^n &\equiv 2-3n+9n^2\qquad\quad\ \ \ \pmod{54}
\end{align}$

Comment: Answer added for the sake of [this dupe](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4164457/242).

Answer (score 0):

When $n$ is even, each term of $2^{2n+1} - 9n^2 + 3n -2$ is even. When $n$ is odd, $-9n^2 + 3n$ is odd + odd = even, hence $2^{2n+1} - 9n^2 + 3n -2$ is even.

Now $2 \cdot 4^{n} - 9n^2 + 3n -2 \equiv 2 \cdot 1^n - 2 \equiv 0 \pmod 3$. Now let $n = 3k$, so $2 \cdot 64^k - 9(3k)^2 + 9k - 2 \equiv$ $ 2\cdot 1^k - 9(3k)^2 + 9k - 2 \equiv 0 \pmod 9$. Letting $k = 9m$, $2 \cdot (64^9)^m - 9(9m)^2 + 81m - 2$ $ \equiv 2 \cdot 1^m - 9(9m)^2 + 81m - 2 \equiv 0 \pmod {27}$. This is because $\phi(27) = 27(1 - 1/3) = 18$, thus $64^{18} \equiv 1 \pmod {27} \implies 64^9 \equiv ±1 \pmod {27}$. But from before, $64^k \equiv 1 \pmod 9$ for $k \in \mathbb Z^+$, so it is congruent to $1$ and not $-1$.