# How to prove divisibility of a number using the binomial expansion?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, binomial-coefficients, binomial-theorem

I have the following problem:

Prove that $6^n-1$ is always divisible by 5 using the binomial expansion of $(5+1)^n$.

How can I do this? I don't know how to begin, as I don't see how the binomial expansion relates to the question. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: [See here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1174078/242) for a better example and  also a presentation using modular arithmetic.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$(5+1)^n-1 =\underbrace{{n\choose 0}5^n+ {n\choose 1}5^{n-1}+...+ {n\choose n-1}5}_{=5\cdot (....)}+1-1 = 5k$$

Answer (score 4):

**HINT:**
$$(5+1)^n=\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k}5^k$$
Which terms of this sum are divisible by $5$?

Comment: (+1) I would have written an answer similar to this.

Answer (score 0):

Guide:

- Treat $a=5$ and $b=1$ in $(a+b)^n$, expand it using binomial expansion. Then subtract it by $1$.
- Then try to factor $5$ out from the remaining term.

Answer (score 0):

$$6^n-1 = (5+1)^n-1$$
$$(5+1)^n = {n \choose 0}5^n+{n \choose 1}5^{n-1}+{n \choose 2}5^{n-2}+{n \choose 3}5^{n-3}+...{n \choose n-1}5^1+{n \choose n}1$$
$$(5+1)^n-1 = {n \choose 0}5^n+{n \choose 1}5^{n-1}+{n \choose 2}5^{n-2}+{n \choose 3}5^{n-3}+...{n \choose n-1}5^1+{n \choose n}1-1$$
${n \choose n}1 = 1$ so $1$ and $-1$ cancel out.
$$\implies (5+1)^n-1 = {n \choose 0}5^n+{n \choose 1}5^{n-1}+{n \choose 2}5^{n-2}+{n \choose 3}5^{n-3}+...{n \choose n-1}5^1$$
All terms have a factor of $5$. Therefore, $6^n-1$ is divisible by $5$.