# For any $a \in \mathbb{N}$, $4^a \equiv (3a+1) \mod 9$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-verification, proof-writing, modular-arithmetic, induction

For any $a \in \mathbb{N}$, $4^a \equiv (3a+1) \mod 9$. How do I prove this?

I have attempted to do so by induction(which I think should be sufficient).

For the base case: $4^0 = 1 \equiv (3(0)+1) \mod 9$.

I have tried assuming the inductive hypothesis $4^a \equiv (3a+1) \mod 9$ to try and get the result to be true for say $a+1$ but I can't get past that point and don't know whether this is the correct route. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: by induction the problem is trivial , just from the inductive stage multiply both sides by 4 and rearrange right hand side you will get an extra 9a term which off course divisible by 9

Comment: @BijayanRay Thanks for your reply. I have already tried that and there is a but there is a remainder 3 there as well.

Comment: how you are getting 12a +4=9a+3(a+1)+1

Comment: Oh my bad, I just realized! Sorry about that.

Answer (score 6):

Hint:

Note that
$$4^a = (3+1)^a = 1+ \binom{a}{1}3 + \binom{a}{2}3^2 + \cdots +3^a=1+3a +9 \left(\binom{a}{2}+ \binom{a}{3}3+\cdots + 3^{a-2} \right)$$

If you insist on induction the induction step can be performed as follows:
\begin{eqnarray*} 4^{a+1}
& \equiv_9 & 4\cdot 4^a \\
& \equiv_9 & (3+1)\cdot (3a+1) \\
& \equiv_9 & 3\cdot (3a+1) + 3a+1 \\
& \equiv_9 & 9a+3 + 3a+1 \\
& \equiv_9 & 3(a+1) +1 \\
\end{eqnarray*}

Comment: A nice solution!

Comment: Just as easy (and more general) to inductively prove the first two terms of the Binomial Theorem, e.g. [see here.](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1174078/242)